# How to give a specific type of function as a parameter in Racket/Plait?

Tags: scheme, racket, plai

I am writing a function that takes in a function and a list as parameters. The parameter function and the list must have the same type of values. How do I ensure that?

I have tried:

```
(define ( (func -> 'a) [lst : (Typeof 'a)])
     ....)
```

However, I have not been able to get it working. I have also gone through the plait tutorial but didn't find anything relevant.

Is it even possible to have a function that accepts a function of a specific return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
(define f : (('a -> 'a) (listof 'a) -> string)
  (lambda (func lst) "hello"))
```

Then:

```
(f (lambda ([x : number]) x) (list 1))
```

type checks, but:

```
(f (lambda ([x : number]) x) (list "foo"))
```

doesn't type check, because `'a` is unified with string (from `"foo"`), but is also unified with number (from `x`), so a type mismatch occurs.

Note that

```
(define f : (('a -> 'a) (listof 'a) -> string)
  (lambda (func lst) "hello"))
```

and

```
(define (f [func : ('a -> 'a)] [lst : (listof 'a)]) : string
  "hello")
```

are different. In the former, `'a` refers to the same type variable across arguments. In the latter, `func`'s `'a` and `lst`'s `'a` are different. Therefore, in the latter, the following expression type checks:

```
(f (lambda ([x : number]) x) (list "foo"))
```